# How can I perform one to one mapping in Ruby using two arrays?

Tags: ruby

I have `array1` with elements `[a1, a2, a3, a4, ... an]` and `array2` with elements `[b1, b2, b3, b4, ... bn]` (both with the same number of elements). How can I create a one to one mapping in Ruby? For example (`a1` with `b1`, `a2` with `b2` and so on). Further I need to use these two elements for executing `curl`. Can you help me to figure out how to do this? I want to perform this in chef. I have tried the following:

```
node[array1].each do |A|
  node[array2].each do |B|
    bash 'Curl Coomad' do
      code <<-EOH
      curl .....
      EOH
    end
  end
end
```

This way it will run `curl` for each and every member of `node[array1]` and `node[array2]`. But I want to use one to one mapping for running this command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Ruby [zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) method, which merges two or more arrays element by element:

```
array1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
array2 = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
array1.zip(array2) #=> [["a1", "b1"], ["a2", "b2"], ["a3", "b3"]]
```

So, then you code would be something like:

```
node[array1].zip(node[array2]).each do |A, B|
  bash 'Curl Coomad' do
    code <<-EOH
    curl .....
    EOH
  end
end
```